# Hover popup code that keeps popup within browser - can ONLY use CSS

Tags: popup, hover

I am in quite a bind with my company's website. My company has spent thousands on this website and I am limited to using a non-open-source CMS system. I had to fight (and we paid $1,200) so I could be provided one CSS page to work in. Our website developers charge us up-the-wazoo for every little change so I cannot ask them to program this (they would probably estimate $3-5k for the work).

Our original lighthouse page, here (live): http://www.golakehavasu.com/activities/more_to_do/lighthouses.aspx has this terrible code where the user clicks on the lighthouse name and a separate window pops up with a photo of the lighthouse. By the time the user is done, 23 separate windows have been opened. Since we are a vacation community and we get a lot of snowbirds in the winter, and I have to explain how to double-click, we get calls from them wondering why our website corrupted their computer (yes, this really happened). I'd love to ignore the calls, but I can't. I needed a better solution for those less web-savvy.

I wanted to convert these images into a hover/popup situation, and although being very limited due to the developer's lockdown of the site (and not being a total tech-head coder), I was able to research some code and get the popups to reasonably work. The test page is here (not live): http://www.golakehavasu.com/test.aspx

One major problem: When getting near the bottom of the lighthouse table, the lighthouse photos are underneath the footer and are not visible; this won't fly with the boss.I need those popups to stay within the browser window, and have zero access to upload a file directly to the server (I can only create pages through the CMS back-end system). My hands are tied here. **Any help would be greatly appreciated, and it would score me some big points with the boss-man (and possibly help to get me hired on full-time with medical insurance benefits).**

I'm trying to copy/paste my code but it's getting stripped. Tried to post the website where I got the code but the system says my reputation is under 10 so I can't post more than 2 links.

Again, please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why I am doing this, other than I am really bored...

Set `.lighthousepopup a:hover span` to have `margin-top: -350px;`.  This will shove the pictures up so the bottom is inline with the hyperlink and they don't fall off the bottom of the screen.

But now you have the same problem on the top, so you'll need to fix the first few rows to not have this using the `nth-child` selector.  Because of the weird layout of the table (caption below the column headers and everything in `tbody`, really?), the first row is actually the 6th, so you'll need to start there.

```
table.grid tr:nth-child(6) td .lighthousepopup a:hover span,
table.grid tr:nth-child(7) td .lighthousepopup a:hover span,
table.grid tr:nth-child(8) td .lighthousepopup a:hover span,
table.grid tr:nth-child(9) td .lighthousepopup a:hover span
{
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

So now rows 1-4 have the top of the image inline with the link, and the rest of the table has the bottom of the image inline with the link.